# Impossible to DETACH database (from c#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I can ATTACH database and copy all the data from one database to another.But on the end i can't detach it using same code.

```
     var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connection)
     connection.Open();
     sqlAttachCommand = "ATTACH database '" + fileLoc + "' AS toMerge";
     var cmd= new SQLiteCommand(sqlAttachCommand);
     cmd.Connection = connection;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     ...
     sqlAttachCommand = "DETACH database '" + fileLoc + "'";
```

The exception is:

> SQL logic error or missing database no such database: C:\temp\database.db".

This is strange because I did attach for it and  I did copy of all the data from this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DETACH DATABASE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) command takes a schema-name as parameter, not a database file.

So your detach command should be like this:

```
sqlAttachCommand = "DETACH database toMerge";
```

as in your ATTACH command you named the thing `toMerge`.

In the SQL Exception the *missing database* isn't referring to the fact that SQLite lost that file, it is mere trying to tell that you're using a schema-name that doesn't exist.